# Vue js can't find page when deployed on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vue-router, firebase-hosting

I'm building a stupid web app to do something funny with my friends. I'm using firebase hosting service and discord oauth2. The problem occurs when trying to access "/login" page by typing it on the url or after pressing "authorize" on the discord link.
You can try it here: https://pelata-gambling.web.app/ (or look the images below), click the green button then click on the blue one. You'll end up in a 404 default page.
So the "/login" page is accessible only if you press the first green button and you can't reach it from anywhere else. I just can't understand how this is happening. This doesn't happen when running the app locally (with npm run dev) and indeed works as intended.

This is the landing page where you are supposed to press the green button
[image: Landing page]

This is the "bugged" page, the one that you can only reach via the previous page
[image: Discord login page]

If you try to access the page by looking for the url  https://pelata-gambling.web.app/login you'll end up in a 404 somehow.

These are the code snippets(let me know if you need more):

Router:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import homepage from '../views/HomePageView.vue'
import discordlogin from '../views/DiscordLoginView.vue'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'homepage',
      component: homepage
    },
    {
      name: "discordlogin",
      path: "/login",
      component: discordlogin
    }
    
    
  ]
})
```

Discord login page (the second page, the one which is unreachable):

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <section class="vh-100 gradient-custom">
      <div class="container py-5 h-100">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
            <div class="card bg-dark text-white" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
              <div class="card-body p-5 text-center">

                <div class="mb-md-5 mt-md-4 pb-5">

                  <h2 class="fw-bold mb-2 text-uppercase">Registrati con Discord</h2>
                  <p class="text-white-50 mb-5">Sarai rindirizzato a discord</p>





                  <button @click="discordLink()" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-5" type="submit">Registrati <img
                      src="../assets/images/discord-ico.png"></button>

                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-center mt-4 pt-1">
                    <a href="#!" class="text-white"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a href="#!" class="text-white"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg mx-4 px-2"></i></a>
                    <a href="#!" class="text-white"><i class="fab fa-google fa-lg"></i></a>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div>
                  <p class="mb-0">Having problems? <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
                      class="text-white-50 fw-bold">I don't care! LMAO</a>
                  </p>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "discordlogin",
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    discordLink() {
      window.location.replace(window.location.hostname === "localhost" ?
        "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=972163681175611&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&scope=identify%20email%20guilds%20guilds.members.read" :
        "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=972163681175611&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpelata-gambling.web.app%2Flogin&response_type=code&scope=identify%20email%20guilds%20guilds.members.read"
      )
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    var qs = require('qs');
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const code = urlParams.get("code")


    console.log(code)
    var data = qs.stringify({
      'client_id': '***',//removed for stackoverflow
      'client_secret': '***',
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'redirect_uri': `${window.location.origin}${window.location.pathname}`,
      'code': code
    });
    var config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

      },
      data: data
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  },
}
</script>

<style>
.btn.btn-outline-light {
  background-color: #5865F2 !important;
  border: 0px !important
}

.btn.btn-outline-light:hover {
  background-color: white !important;
  border: 0px !important
}
</style>
```

Thanks to everyone who is trying to help

EDIT: i removed `mode: 'history'` from the router config and seems to work now but it's still weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing `mode: 'history'` from the router config solved my issue but i don't know if it is a good solution

Comment: Hi, it will be helpful if you can further expand on why your answer works. It could be that you read it in an article in which case it would be helpful to share that article. Or sharing your operating system and environment. This extra bit of information will be helpful to not just the poster but to anyone who finds your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, i've just looked at my previous projects in Vue3 and noticed that some of them didn't have   `mode: 'history' . That's all i have done, I have no idea what mode does and didn't even know it existed, indeed i specified that i don't even know if it is a good answer. If an explained answer will ever come i'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

when clicking the green button, your browser sends an [HTTP POST Request](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to discord's oauth api.

[image]

and that's what being shown in the page.

the `"/login"` is fake, and is pushed in through [js trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) in `/static/js/app.7ad2bbe6ea8f108e3c9a.js`

[image]

and by the way, even if it did exist, it's legit to only serve it to POST requests (so 404 will return if someone tries to access it via GET.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do i make that the login page "not fake"?. I used vue-router as configured with vue-cli (i think) and didn't change it much ( i just added my pages). I removed the `mode: 'history'` from the router and now the page is reachable at https://pelata-gambling.web.app/#/login but i don't understand why.